# Fix an error? Reading from File

Tags: java

**My output is:**

> IKE Dinner 25.00 04/15/1993
>
> HUNTER Dinner 50.00 DATE1
>
> STEVE Lodging 25.00 DATE2
>
> ROY Lodging 50.00 DATE3
>
> MAX Conference 25.00 DATE4File contents invalid.

**How do I fix the error?
It is reading from the file "hotel" with contents:**

> IKE;Dinner;25.00;04/15/1993;
>
> HUNTER;Dinner;50.00;DATE1;
>
> STEVE;Lodging;25.00;DATE2;
>
> ROY;Lodging;50.00;DATE3;
>
> MAX;Conference;25.00;DATE4;

**Expected Output:**

> IKE Dinner 25.00 04/15/1993
>
> HUNTER Dinner 50.00 DATE1
>
> STEVE Lodging 25.00 DATE2
>
> ROY Lodging 50.00 DATE3
>
> MAX Conference 25.00 DATE4
>
> Dinner: TOTAL Conference: TOTAL Lodging: TOTAL

**CODE**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class P7Point16 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    double dinner = 0;
    double conference = 0;
    double lodging = 0;
    String name = null, service = null, amount = null, date = null;

    File file = new File(
            "DIRECTORY\\src\\hotel");

    Scanner read = null;
    try {
        read = new Scanner(file);

        read.useDelimiter(";");

        while (read.hasNextLine()) {
            if(read.hasNext()) {
            name = read.next();
            service = read.next();
            amount = read.next();
            date = read.next();

            if (service.equalsIgnoreCase("Lodging")) {
                lodging += Double.parseDouble(amount);
            } else if (service.equalsIgnoreCase("Conference")) {
                conference += Double.parseDouble(amount);
            } else if (service.equalsIgnoreCase("Dinner")) {
                dinner += Double.parseDouble(amount);
            }
            System.out.print(name + " " + service + " " + amount + " "
                    + date);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Dinner: " + dinner + " Conference: "
                + conference + " Lodging: " + lodging);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {
        System.out.println("File not found.");
    } catch (NoSuchElementException exception) {
        System.out.println("File contents invalid.");
    } finally {
        read.close();
    }
}
}
```

**WORKING CODE**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class P7Point16 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double dinner = 0;
    double conference = 0;
    double lodging = 0;
    String name = null, service = null, amount = null, date = null;

    File file = new File(
            "DIRECTORY\\src\\hotel");

    Scanner read = null;
    try {
        read = new Scanner(file);

        read.useDelimiter(";");

        while (read.hasNext()) {

            name = read.next();
            service = read.next();
            amount = read.next();
            date = read.next();

            if (service.equalsIgnoreCase("Lodging")) {
                lodging += Double.parseDouble(amount);
            } else if (service.equalsIgnoreCase("Conference")) {
                conference += Double.parseDouble(amount);
            } else if (service.equalsIgnoreCase("Dinner")) {
                dinner += Double.parseDouble(amount);
            }
            System.out.print(name + " " + service + " " + amount + " "
                    + date);
            }
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Dinner: " + dinner + " Conference: "
                + conference + " Lodging: " + lodging);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {
        System.out.println("File not found.");
    } catch (NoSuchElementException exception) {
        System.out.println("File contents invalid.");
    } finally {
        read.close();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: Added output expected

Comment: When posting code online you should not post the absolute directory.  I was always advised to do something along the lines of `"..//location"`.  Just a safety precaution.

Comment: Is it possible you're getting this exception because you're closing the scanner too early? I don't know if this may work, but try closing the scanner after the last console print. `System.out.println("Dinner: " + dinner + " Conference: "+conference + " Lodging: " + lodging);`

Comment: I changed the code in the main post to avoid this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
while (read.hasNextLine()) {
```

to

```
while (read.hasNext()) {
```

Comment: This was the solution

Answer (score 0):

It seems likely that your file has a blank line at the end. When you call

```
name = read.next();
```

You get an exception that tells you "there are no more elements in this sequence!"

If you want to handle malformed lines in your file, you can use code like the following:

```
    while (read.hasNextLine()) 
    {
    ...
        if(read.hasNext())
        {
            // read a token
        }
        else
        {
            // exit gracefully
        }
    ...
    }
```

Comment: File has no extra lines

Comment: Added 
if(read.hasNext())
{
etc
}

Now the code is constantly looking for input still

Comment: I say it seems likely, because that's the only thing I see in the code that throws a NoSuchElementException

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a newline at the end of last line of your input file, so read.hasNextLine() finds an extra (blank) line after the last line of data.